# How can I attach pictures to a post?

Tags: support, faq, questions, answers

I need to include a picture in my post. How can I do this? Is there a preferred method, on Drupal Answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the *Insert Image* toolbar button [image: image button]
2. A dialog box will appear

   > [image]
3. Drag and drop the file to the dialog box, or click on the area for the drag and drop for uploading a local image
4. To upload an image for which you have a link, click on *link from the web*
5. In the latter case, enter the image URL, not the link for a page containing the image

   > [image: screenshot]
6. In both the cases, click on *Add picture*

   > [image: screenshot]

#### Note

You need to be registered member in the site with at least 10 reputation in order to [gain the privilege to use this feature](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user).

After that, replace the default "enter image description here" with something meaningful for browsers that do not support images.

Even when providing a link to an image hosted in some sites, the image will be copied to the Stack Exchange Imgur account, and hence will be safe from expiring.

If you just want a link to an image:

1. Use the steps above
2. Remove the leading exclamation point from the result: `[click for my image][6]`

If you *really* want to hardlink images from another source, without copying them to the Stack Exchange Imgur account:

1. Use the link tool to make a regular link to the image
2. Prepend the link with an exclamation point: `![Image description][7]`

Bear in mind that:

- To make it easier to find relevant information using search engines, be sure to copy important text into your post too, and not to use a screenshot simply for showing text, if you don't want to merely show the style of the text. (Messages from popup dialogs can often simply be copied using Ctrl-C or Command-C.)
- For the screen readers of visually impaired, for browsers that don't show images, for cases [where Imgur is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64402/cannot-see-pictures-on-stack-overflow), and for search engine indexes please enter a good description.
- Whenever possible, use the Stack Exchange provided hosting as described below. This uses an [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) Pro account, which ensures images are never lost. Images on *free* Imgur accounts, and on many other free image hosters, will expire if not requested every now and then. The post should be useful for future visitors too.